# Як перекласти російське словосполучення "можно и нужно"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian, фразеологізми

У російській мові є словосполучення, яке означає, що деяка дія є не лише можливою, але й бажаною, рекомендованою:

> *можно и нужно*

Це словосполучення є досить зручним у використанні завдяки своїй напів-римованості. Зручність його також підсилюється тим, що зазвичай під час реального діалогу можна казати спочатку *«можно»*, а потім, через паузу, додати: *«и нужно»*.

Запитання: **Чи є подібний еквівалент в українській мові?**

Обов'язковою умовою є (напів-)римованість двох частин словосполучення. Вочевидь, варіанти *«можна і бажано»* або *«можна і потрібно»* не підходять під цю умову.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55114/discussion-between-chizh-and-bytebuster).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суб'єктивна відповідь, на яку надихнув [Artemix](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/69/artemix)

Оскільки автор запитання сам поставив під сумнів існування єдино правильного відповідника, я спробувала придумати власний варіант.

Критеріями підбору слугували вимоги автора запитання:

1. (Напів)римованість двох частин словосполучення.
2. Під час реального діалогу можна казати спочатку перше слово, а потім, через паузу, додати друге.

Пошуки в [Практичному словнику синонімів української мови](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Karavanskyy_Sviatoslav/Praktychnyi_slovnyk_synonimiv_ukrainskoi_movy/) Святослава Караванського й визначили мій вибір.

Оскільки слово **вільно** подається першим варіантом у синонімічному ряду до *можна*, то це **вільно** швидко заримувалося з двома синонімами-перекладами *нужно* - **потрібно** і **необхідно**.

Таким чином, маємо два варіанти, які відповідають першому критерію:

**Вільно і потрібно** / **вільно і необхідно**.

Для підсилення ефекту і для відповідності другому критерію, можна, замінивши сполучник, отримати:

**Вільно, ба й потрібно** / **Вільно, ба й необхідно**.

[БА 3, спол.](http://sum.in.ua/s/ba)

> БА 3, спол.
>   1. Уживається для приєднання речень, що уточнюють зміст попередніх; значенням близький до та й, навіть. Ще в гімназії Борис займав видне
>   місце серед товаришів, ба й учителі гляділи на нього як на головну
>   оздобу закладу (Іван Франко, III, 1950, 29); Наступний день Панас
>   зустрів спокійно, ба навіть поважно, як годиться старшому в сім'ї
>   (Яків Качура, Вибр., 1953, 451);

**Прим.** Хоча запропоновані варіанти й не є у широкому вжитку, принаймні я маю намір їх використовувати у відповідному контексті. Буду рада, якщо бодай ще хтось ними скористається :)